# What's the intuition behind variational learning in Deep NNs with attention mechanism

Tags: neural-networks, intuition, variational

I'm trying to understand this paper: ["Multiple Object Recognition With Visual Attention (Ba et al., 2015)"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7755v2.pdf), specifically I'm trying to understand section 3. which explains how the model is trained.

Please let me jump right to the question, without re-introducing the notation from the paper.

Authors state:

> We can maximize likelihood of the class label by marginalizing over
>   the glimpse locations: $$ \log\ p(y\ |\ I, W) = \log\sum_l p(l\ |\ I, W)\
> > p(y\ |\ l, I, W) $$
>
> The marginalized objective function can be learned through optimizing its variational free energy
>   lower bound $\mathcal{F}$: $$ \log\sum_l p(l\ |\ I, W)\ p(y\ |\ l, I, W) \geq \sum_l p(l\ |\ I, W)\ \log\ p(y\ |\ l, I, W) $$
>
> The learning rules can be derived by taking derivatives of the above
>   free energy with respect to the model parameter W: $$ \frac{∂\mathcal{F}}{∂W} = \sum_l p(l\ |\ I, W) \left[ \frac{∂\ \log p(y\ |\ l, I, W)}{∂W} + \log p(y\ |\ l, I, W) \frac{∂\ \log p(l\ |\ I, W)}{∂W} \right] $$
>
> Which can be approximated:
>
> $$ \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=1}^M \left[ \frac{∂\ \log p(y\ |\ l^m, I, W)}{∂W} + \log\ p(y\ |\ l^m, I, W) \frac{∂\ \log\ p(l^m\ |\ I, W)}{∂W} \right] $$

I don't really see how this learning rule allows the net to learn where to attend. The way I think about this now is:
- whenever the network happens to attend to a relevant piece of image, $ \log\ p(y) $ is quite large, therefore the gradient is updated in a way to maximze $\log\ p(l^m)$ but I don't think this is correct.

Would it be possible for someone to provide me with an intuitive explanation about what's going on, or at least point me to relevant literature?

Comment: I am also trying to read this paper. I think if you also take into account that the network is also trying to learn p(l) [specifically mean and variance of the prob distribution]. so it learn p(l) and p(y|l) both together. After that it make sense. This book http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ specially chapter 20 has some explanation.